# Strange Null Reference Error while adding element to IList

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I've got a very confusing problem with a null reference error. It reads as:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameHandler.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/GameHandler.cs:33)
```

Here's the lengthy context:

C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject canvas;

IList<GameObject> selected;
GameObject[] troopObjects;
bool isSelecting = false;
Vector3 mousePosition1;

void Update() {
    // If we press the left mouse button, save mouse location and begin selection
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        isSelecting = true;
        mousePosition1 = Input.mousePosition;
        if(selected != null) {
            foreach (GameObject selectedTroop in selected) {
                selectedTroop.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
            };
        };
        selected = null;
    };
    // If we let go of the left mouse button, end selection
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        isSelecting = false;
    };
    if (isSelecting) {
        troopObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Troop");
        foreach (GameObject troop in troopObjects) {
            if (IsWithinSelectionBounds(troop)) {
                selected.Add(troop);
                troop.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            };
        };
    };
    if (selected != null) {

    };

}
// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    canvas.SetActive(false);
}

void OnGUI() {
    if (isSelecting) {
        // Create a rect from both mouse positions
        var rect = Utils.GetScreenRect(mousePosition1, Input.mousePosition);
        Utils.DrawScreenRect(rect, new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.95f, 0.25f));
        Utils.DrawScreenRectBorder(rect, 2, new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.95f));
    }
}

public bool IsWithinSelectionBounds(GameObject gameObject) {
    if (!isSelecting)
        return false;

    var camera = Camera.main;
    var viewportBounds = Utils.GetViewportBounds(camera, mousePosition1, Input.mousePosition);
    return viewportBounds.Contains(camera.WorldToViewportPoint(gameObject.transform.position));
}
}
```

Now the problem code would appear to be this right here:

```
if (isSelecting) {
    troopObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Troop");
    foreach (GameObject troop in troopObjects) {
        if (IsWithinSelectionBounds(troop)) {
            selected.Add(troop);
            troop.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        };
    };
};
```

What the error is referencing is this:

```
selected.Add(troop);
```

It's saying that "troop" is a null reference. Now when I remove this line of code, the rest works just fine. Which makes no sense because right after that problem code, there is this:

```
troop.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Which uses that same "troop" reference. I would love for some assistance on this one because it's got me stumped. If any extra information is needed just let me know.

Comment: Umm, I'm pretty sure it's `selected` that's `null`, not `troop`. It's not like adding a `null` value to a list is forbidden... In fact, you're never filling `selected` and you're explicitly setting it to `null` :)

Comment: troop is not null, the list is !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are nullifying the instance and then based on some condition trying to add the elements to the NULL object. That is not right.

Please change this line :

```
selected = null;
```

to this :

```
selected.Clear();
```

And instantiate the list in the beginning :

```
void Update() {
selected = new List<GameObject>();
```

Comment: Why is the downvote here? I would like to improve my understanding please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the troop is null, not selected?  Your code above checks selected and if it is not null it nulls it.

```
selected = null;
```